# Logic for Redirecting to next page by Jquery year picker and swiper slider while selecting one image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Am a beginner to javascript. In a page i have created slider images and in down i have placed a Jquery date Picker(it selects the year).

Scenario:
When i select one image in the slider and select the year it must redirect to next page.

Submit button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
let _img = document.getElementById("img");
let _img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
let _img2 = document.getElementById("img2");
let _picker = document.getElementById("picker");
let _btn = document.getElementById("button");

let isImgClicked = false;
let isDatePicked = false;
_img.addEventListener("click", function(){
  isImgClicked = true;
});
_img1.addEventListener("click", function(){
  isImgClicked = true;
});
_img2.addEventListener("click", function(){
  isImgClicked = true;
});
_picker.addEventListener("click", function(){
  isDatePicked = true;
});
_btn.addEventListener("click", function(){

              if(!isImgClicked || !isDatePicked)
              {
                  alert("select the Year and Click the car image");

              }
              else 
                 {
                  if((isImgClicked == "img") && (isDatePicked == "2020"))
                     {
                        window.location.replace("sample.html");
                     }
                  else if((isImgClicked == "img") && (isDatePicked == "2019"))
                     {
                   window.location.replace("sample1.html");
                     }
                  else
                      {
                        if((isImgClicked == "img1") && (isDatePicked == "2019"))
                  {
                  window.location.replace("sample2.html");
                  }
              else if((isImgClicked == "img1") && (isDatePicked == "2020"))
                  {
                   window.location.replace("sample3.html");
                  }
              else
                  {
                  alert("!!!!")
                  }
                 }
                 }
        });
</script>
```

Code:

```
<script>
  function Redirect()
  {
      window.location="sample.jsp"
  }
  </script>

<div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(./img/Eco.png)" onclick="Redirect();" id="eco"><b>Eco</b></div>
```

Jpicker year:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            changeYear: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            dateFormat: 'yy',
            onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
                var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, 1));
            }
        });

       $("#datepicker").focus(function () {
            $(".ui-datepicker-month").hide();
            $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide();
        });

    });
  </script>

html:<p align="center"><b>Year:</b> <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

This code redirects to next page when i click on that image. But i need to Redirect when i select the year and image and while clicking on submitting it must rediect to next page.
Can someone pls help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code suggests `onclick="Redirect();"` to be called when you click on the image.

Two things can be done here,

1. In `Redirect` function, check if the date is picked by the user, if not, prompt to pick a date and once picked then redirect.
2. Create a different `submit` button. On click of `image` and `date picker`, maintain different boolean which will set to true. On click of `submit`, check if both the booleans are true and then redirect, else prompt to error for the boolean which is `false`

```js
let _img = document.getElementById("img")
let _picker = document.getElementById("picker")
let _btn = document.getElementById("btn")

let isImgClicked = false
let isDatePicked = false
_img.addEventListener("click", () => {
  isImgClicked = true
})
_picker.addEventListener("click", () => {
  isDatePicked = true
})
_btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (!isImgClicked)
    alert("Image Not clicked")
  else if (!isDatePicked)
    alert("Date not picked")
  else
    alert("All good! Need to reirect")
})
```

```html
<img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/w_400,h_400,c_crop,g_face,r_max/w_200/lady.jpg" id="img">

<div id="picker">
  Dummy date picker
</div>

<button id="btn">
  Submit
</button>
```

Above is a basic code representation of the 2nd approach in vanilla javascript.

Comment: Please upvote and accept this as an answer if you find this helpful. It would help others too to identify the answer.

Comment: I have editted the submit code above. But in the else condition there contains a string value for a boolean, thus the else condition is not getting executed. can you pls help me here.